# Почему @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) тригерит 2 SQL вместо 1?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть простое энтити Restaurant, которое имеет список Vote ( Ненужные методы и филды не показаны )

```
public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Vote> votes;
```

}
Вот другая сторона отношений

```
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

}

Когда я получаю данные при помощи метода findAll() от Spring Data JPA и конверчу их через ДТО маппер вот так

```
@Cacheable(value = "restaurantDTOList", key = "-1")
public List<RestaurantResponseDTO> getAll() {
    List<Restaurant> restaurantList = restaurantRepository.findAll();
    return restaurantList.stream()
            .map(RestaurantMapper::toRestaurantDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

public static RestaurantResponseDTO toRestaurantDto(Restaurant restaurant) {

```
    return new RestaurantResponseDTO(restaurant.getId(), restaurant.getName(),
            restaurant.getAddress(), getRestaurantVoteCount(restaurant));
}
public static long getRestaurantVoteCount(Restaurant restaurant) {
var votes = restaurant.getVotes();
if (votes == null) return 0;
return  votes.stream().filter(vote -> vote.getVoteDate().equals(LocalDate.now())).count();
```

}
Я получаю эти SQL

```
    Hibernate: 
select
    restaurant0_.id as id1_1_,
    restaurant0_.name as name2_1_,
    restaurant0_.address as address3_1_ 
from
    restaurant restaurant0_

Hibernate: 
select
    votes0_.restaurant_id as restaura3_4_1_,
    votes0_.id as id1_4_1_,
    votes0_.id as id1_4_0_,
    votes0_.restaurant_id as restaura3_4_0_,
    votes0_.user_id as user_id4_4_0_,
    votes0_.vote_date as vote_dat2_4_0_ 
from
    vote votes0_ 
where
    votes0_.restaurant_id in (
        select
            restaurant0_.id 
        from
            restaurant restaurant0_
    )
```

Буду крайне благодарен, если поможете разобраться, почему 2 SQL, а не одно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ожидаемое поведение.

Вот что говорит [документация](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#SUBSELECT) про `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`:

> When accessing a non-initialized collection, this fetch mode will trigger loading all elements of all collections of the same role for all owners associated with the persistence context using a single secondary select.

Вольный перевод:

> При доступе к неинициализированной коллекции этот режим инициирует загрузку всех элементов этой ассоциации для всех сущностей в контексте используя один дополнительный запрос.

Этот режим есть смысл использовать, когда у вас основной запрос возвращает несколько сущностей (и они большие, т.е. содержат много данных), а ассоциированных с ними сущностей много. В этом случае при `FetchMode.SELECT` сделает `N+1` запрос, чего хочется избежать. Использование `FetchMode.JOIN` приведет к тому, что колонки из основной сущности будут дублироваться в результате. Это дублирование привет к тому, что будет передано много данных (т.е. для каждой ассоциированной сущности данные в родителе будут повторятся, и напоминаю, мы говорим о ситуации, когда родитель - большой), которые можно не передавать, если не делать join, а доставать ассоциированные сущности отдельным запросом.

Вот именно для этой ситуации и годится `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`.